# Cannot perform estimation via MHRM algorithm in mirt package

Tags: r, package, estimation, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to estimate a mmultilevel multidimensional item response theory (MMIRT) model in R by using *mirt* package (Chalmers, R. Philip. "mirt: A multidimensional item response theory package for the R environment." Journal of statistical Software 48 (2012): 1-29.). The function *mixedmirt()* is supposed to do this via the Metropolis-Hastings Robbins-Monro (*MHRM*) algorithm but, for some reason, I get the following message.

```
> library(mirt)

> 2l.model <- mixedmirt(data = my.data, model = EUR, itemtype = "graded", survey.weights = my.weights, fixed =~ 0, random =~ 1 | my.groups)
Error in ESTIMATION(data = data, model = model, group = rep("all", nrow(data)),  : 
  opts$method %in% c("EM", "QMCEM", "MCEM") non è TRUE
```

So, I tried to change the method as suggested by the error line. However, as clearly explained in the documentation of the function, this is not allowed (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mirt/versions/1.37.1/topics/mixedmirt).

```
> 2l.model <- mixedmirt(data = my.data, model = my.model, itemtype = "graded", method = "QMCEM", survey.weights = my.weights, fixed =~ 0, random =~ 1 | my.groups)
Error: method cannot be changed in mixedmirt() function
```

Furthermore, I checked if the *MHRM* method worked for unilevel mirt models by using the function *mirt()*, which should be allowed according to the documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mirt/versions/1.37.1/topics/mirt). However, once again, I get the following message.

```
> mirt.model <- mirt(data = my.data, model = my.model, method = "MHRM", survey.weights = my.weights)
Error in ESTIMATION(data = data, model = model, group = rep("all", nrow(data)),  : 
  opts$method %in% c("EM", "QMCEM", "MCEM") non è TRUE
```

All this evidence led me to the conclusion that there is something wrong which prevent me to use the *MHRM* algorithm in my code or perhaps in my laptop. If so, is there a way to fix the problem and perform a estimation via the *MHRM* algorithm?

All the code was run in R 4.2.2 version.

Comment: Strange indeed. Do any of the examples run from the documentation. What version of mirt are you using?

Comment: Hi, all the examples from the documentation run as expected. May this problem depend on my data set? I am using version 1.37.1.